# URL Stop using Delphi service

Tags: delphi, url, browser

I want to have background service written in Delphi 7, that stops a specific URL from being loaded by any browser. Is this possible?

Can anyone point me in a direction?

Thanks in advance.

Shane

Comment: You can achieve this by editing `hosts` file. See [this](http://www.jafaloo.com/2013/01/03/windows-hosts-file/) to find out how to do this. No need to write windows service.

Comment: If the `hosts` file isn't an adequate solution, then you can look at programming a driver in C/C++ that filters HTTP traffic.  This however is not a trivial task.  My friend is a Windows device driver programmer and said this kind of project start around 10,000 lines of code, and can only be written in C/C++.

Comment: @Adam, as I said in a comment to [Golez answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15414851/255257), editing the hosts file works only if the browser doesn't use a proxy. If a proxy is used, what you suggest is useless.

Comment: @jachguate Of course you are right.

Comment: Another thought, you can use OpenDNS (a free DNS service that lets you filter domains based on their content rating) and add the unwanted `domain` to the block list.  This blocks it for all computers at your location (that access the internet through a common Public IP address) from accessing the blocked domain.  Still doesn't solve the proxy server issue though, or computers where the DNS is manually set to something other then the OpenDNS servers.

Comment: Last thought: You may want to look at NDIS Filter Driver (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565492(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches of which the second one is technically the best:

- Write a DLL that you [inject into all processes](https://www.google.com/search?q=delphi+dll+injection) and if these processes are for a browser you have to intercept and filter all traffic, e.g. using Windows sockets
- Write a [Layered service provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) that works a bit like a firewall (at a lower level in the OS)

I've worked in internet filtering software and I can tell you both are *big* undertakings.
We initially took the first approach, then switched to the other because it's technically better. [And we never finished that transition because the company folded ;-(]

We did not write our own LSP (it's a big job in itself) but used the products from [Komodia](http://www.komodia.com/). Although they write for C, the people were very helpful answering our questions about porting to Delphi.

But as I said earlier, this is BIG: you have to deal with 32 and 64 bit code, http versus https, protecting services from being stopped, etc. Any non-programming solution that you can find is better (although easy to circumvent).

If you still want to program: prepare for 1 man-year of coding using LSP.

Answer (score 1):

A service, no, I don't think so. But you can edit the 'hosts' file so that the domain of the url points to 127.0.0.1. You can make a service that 'guards' this file, although the service itself must have elevated rights to be able to edit it, and of course, the service itself can be killed as well, if the user has the rights to do so.

Anyway, if you manage to edit the file, the browser will not be able to find the server by domain name. Of course, urls with an IP address cannot be blocked this way and neither can you block specific urls, only the entire domain.

But in general, this is not something to solve using a custom service, but in the firewall on either the PC or the router.

Comment: The hosts file trick works if the browser connect directly to the site, but not if a proxy is used.

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer, you can write a [Browser Helper Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that IE itself loads and passes browser events to.  The BHO can then accept/reject URLS on a per-request basis as needed.

Comment: The question was specifically for ANY browser.

Comment: @MikeD: I realize that, but there is no single answer that accounts for all browsers generically, short of creating/using an external proxy that implements a blacklist. Since each browser implements its own HTTP engine privately, you would have to either re-configure each browser to pass through your proxy, or else write browser-specific hooks for each browser individually (like a BHO for IE) if an external proxy is not an option.

Comment: All very good, but thinking outside the box, I think it can be done in a week.